# iTextSharp : merge the last column (Colspan)

Tags: c#, reporting, itext

I have a table, this table has 3 columns. In each column, there is a table like the picture. 
I did a method to generate table, this method receive a list in argument and loop on it to 
addCell to the table

I'd like for a line has a instead of 5 columns ... 1 + 1 (colspan of 4). When I do a colspan
the 4 first are merged, I'd like merged the 4 last and keep the first.

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to add the cells to the table in the order that you want them to span. If you add the spanned cells before the first cell then that's how they'll appear.

```
PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(5);
//Row 1
t.AddCell("R1C1");
t.AddCell("R1C2");
t.AddCell("R1C3");
t.AddCell("R1C4");
t.AddCell("R1C5");

//Row 2 - One regular cell followed by four spanned cells
t.AddCell("R2C1");
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("R2C2-5")) { Colspan = 4 });

//Row 3 - Four spanned cells followed by one regular cell
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("R3C1-4")) { Colspan = 4 });
t.AddCell("R3C5");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        table.AddCell("Row 1, Col 1");
        table.AddCell("Row 1, Col 2");
        table.AddCell("Row 1, Col 3");

        table.AddCell("Row 2, Col 1");
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("R2, C2")) { Colspan = 2 }); // table.AddCell("Row 2, Col 2");
        //table.AddCell("Row 2, Col 3");

        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("R3, C1")) { Rowspan = 2 }); //table.AddCell("Row 3, Col 1");
        table.AddCell("Row 3, Col 2");
        table.AddCell("Row 3, Col 3");

        //table.AddCell("Row 4, Col 1");
        table.AddCell("Row 4, Col 2");
        table.AddCell("Row 4, Col 3");
```